# Abrir en página web con el PDF?

Tags: java, android

Porque este código no debería mostrar el pdf del link?

```
 public void cambio2018 (View view){    
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.ujaen.es/servicios/negapoyo/sites/servicio_negapoyo/files/uploads/Modelo%20Archivo%20en%20Formato%20Digital.pdf"), "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
```

No me da ningún error pero se queda en blanco la app y vuelve a la activity anterior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lo que deseas realizar puede funcionar únicamente si tu dispositivo tiene alguna aplicación instalada que pueda manipular archivos del formato definido por el `MIME TYPE` `"application/pdf"`**, de lo contrario no podrá abrirlo.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();            
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.ujaen.es/servicios/negapoyo/sites/servicio_negapoyo/files/uploads/Modelo%20Archivo%20en%20Formato%20Digital.pdf"), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Si no tienes una app queda abrir el .pdf, una opción es usar `ACTION_VIEW` que descargaría el PDF:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: con el ACTION_VIEW me descarga el pdf no lo muestra, podria usar un webview?

Comment: así es, si quieres usar un WebView, el PDF debe ser antes descargado a disco y posteriormente cargarlo a tu WebView.